# Airport radar is interfering with my circuitry

Tags: emi-filtering

I am using an arduino, but this is not an arduino question. And unfortunately, I cannot share my schematic. I can tell you though that I have a stack of three arduino-sized boards which create two ground loops, each about the size of an arduino. I also have an RFID reader board connected, which has about a 2 inch coil in it. But it seems like that coil should be isolated from the arduino by the RFID board's ICs. Altogether I'm pulling a max of around 250 mA out of 6 AA batteries, though the actual current draw varies on short timescales as I transmit wireless data via Xbee.

Somewhere, I'm picking up noise, and it's only happening when I take my devices closer to the radar station about a half mile away. It's actually crashing and rebooting my arduino program. I'm positive an external source is the culprit. since tinfoil shielding prevents the problem, but I cannot add shielding to my design until a later date.

My coworkers and I believe the noise must be affecting the power to my processor, since it seems like processor voltage drops/spikes would most certainly be the only things to cause such behavior in the microcontroller. If that's the case, then I should be able to add line filters. Does that seem reasonable?

I could apply filters to the main power into the arduino, and also add something to the 5V and 3.3V output buses to the peripherals. My initial instinct is to add a 1000uF low-ESR electrolytic across the main power, and some smaller 470uF caps across the 5V and 3.3V buses. But I know it should depend on the frequency of the noise I'm trying to filter. Airport radar operates in the 2.7G range, so I guess I should try filtering 2.7G, right?

Is this the right way to go about the problem?

Comment: You have an EMI problem. Without even looking, it’s statistically due to poor PCB and cable layout. Electrolytes have crap zero to say at 2.7 GHz.

Comment: As stated, I have ground loops. Should I be using ceramics?

Comment: If you are close to a rotating radar array the power density may be very high. You primarily need shielding. Adding filters will not prevent direct response to focused microwave signals. Build a Faraday cage and protect the cable entry ports.

Comment: Fix your layout first!

Comment: Why do boards reboot? Maybe you have a reset line that is floating? Maybe an interrupt line is floating? If you don't have a handler, then who knows what the interrupt may do? Couldn't hurt to add caps (don't ask us, just try it), but I would also work backwards from the question of "what io pin could cause this to happen?"

Comment: @winny - I would, but it's too late for this revision in the product lifecycle.

Comment: Apart from the RFID, what other input/output to those processors do you have? Any I/O over-volt or under-volt could trigger those nasty parasitic internal latch-up devices lurking inside these processors....have seen too many Arduino go berserk this way. As Tony suggests, EMI-filter I/O locally. Don't just assume that power rails suck in radar pulses. Those 3-board ground loops could be a real pain to suppress (at 2.7 GHz). A mesh-type ground connection would need quite a fine pitch.

Comment: I do have other periprials. An LCD screen, some LEDs, an input from a voltage divider, a camera, and a couple of other pins that lead to 5V linear regulator gates used to power lasers. The're all set as outputs in the code except for the voltage divider input (used as a battery indication). Thanks for the advice, man.

Comment: How did you pass CE/FCC?

Comment: Well, it isn't a consumer product. It's a tool we use internal to the company. And it's a big company, so even though I designed and built these things, I don't have the authority to just open them up and change them at any time since they're "owned" by our internal "customer". I can probably add caps/filters though, since that's a quick fix.

Comment: There are no quick fixes at 2.7 GHz unless you can change the physical appearance somehow by effectively shrinking your loop area.

Comment: I'm going to give these a try: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/murata-electronics-north-america/RCE5C1H390J0A2H03B/490-11873-ND/4277646

Comment: It's worh a try at least. And I might still try a high-frequency  ferrite bead on the input power.

Comment: How short do you aim to cut down those leads? What inductance will you have of what’s left. What is the dominant factor for what you end up with, ESL or C being dominant at 2.7 GHz.

Comment: I can't shorten the leads, and I still have no idea what piece of copper is picking up the offending noise. It doesn't make sense for me to start redesigning each end every wire for optimal L/C at this point in time. If I was able to change the design right now, I'd just integrate shielding to the enclosure and be done with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Radar Pi filters and ferrite beads in addition to shielded pairs or signals will correct your problem as long as the ground and slots in a case don't resonate the signal.

> Murata has the right NPO caps in the <50 pF range and ferrite CM filters and chokes for microwave.  All IO cable signals need capacitive to ground feedthrus and CM chokes. Exposed boards need a good ground plane or earthed box.

### Experience

Burroughs had a similar problem on the top floors of Richardson Security Exchange in Winnipeg. The tallest building still at Portage and Main. The 207 14" Disk drive was getting random errors on the read-write chain serial differential data.

Factoid: Since Bill Richardson's family had a long history of wealth and he became a Pierre Trudeau cabinet minister. he had pull.. so it is written into the city bylaws that no building in Winnipeg can be taller than his.  Little did they know about Radar.

But then down the block, where NRC was inventing mobile 7 Tesla medical scanners, every CRT in the building when the MRI was fired up in the basement.  Metal Chairs were once reported to be once pulled in at lethal velocities across the room and any credit card anywhere inside the chamber would get demagnetized.

It needed an EMI fix ... fast.

The customer was the biggest Investment company around and data records were getting infrequently but randomly corrupted.

It was Wpg Intl  Airport Radar.

The field fix took a few days, to patch and weeks for general production after test verification. It was my 3rd employer and it happened just before I got there in 1982.

Comment: I'm nowhere near an expert on EMI. How did you (or someone else) was able to identify that the Radar was causing that corruption? How do you rule out other possibilities and drill down to this particular root cause?

Comment: They took a 300 MHz Tek scope out and observed the 1kHz pulse amplitude modulation.  THose who did it like myself are EMI experts.

Comment: Interesting. So the effect was observed at 1kHz, was that different from the actual radar driving frequency?

Comment: @LegitimateWorkUser  Data point only: Lonnnng ago. Wellington City, NZ. All the phones in Telecom office suddenly started repeatedly making a brief "tinkle" a few seconds apart. A look out the window at the harbour showed that the timing exactly corresponded to the rotation time of the large RADAR antenna on the US warship in the bay. A condition of entry had been that the RADAR was not used.  People ran ... .

Comment: The 1us pulse had a 1kpps from radar.  The same issue occurs in Op Amps and CMOS with input diodes rectifying AM carrier.  peak power of 1.3 MW

Comment: In my 1st job, my draftsman, told me how WWII tanker pilots fainted when they stood up outside from the kW Radar over their heads.  It was a Darwin moment for engineers then

Comment: You can be sure Mobile antenna towers are carefully placed and on roof tops. But I wonder about ground reflections on ice (known issuue for fading) and side lobes  to nearby apartments. Stick your kabob out the window..  I always had the urge to field test stray EMI levels but there are 10 thousand mobile towers in Toronto alone.

Comment: Warship Radar can reach 10MW peak levels.

Comment: That's pretty scary if you're into having kids with more traditional numbers of arms and legs.

Comment: not as bad as Florida "fresh" water from pesticides and fertilizer